# How can I add custom entries to "Create New" on KDE Plasma?

Tags: kde, desktop-environment, plasma5, file-manager, file-management

I'm using KDE Plasma, and frequently need to package file sets into tar.gz or zip. This usually requires opening Ark, creating a new file, and working from there, which is a run-around. It would be better if I could right-click in the Dolphin workspace for a directory, go the "Create New..." submenu, and pick this file type out; but as of the moment, the only options are:

Folder...
Text File...
LibreOffice Calc/Draw/Impress/Writer...
Link to Location/File/Directory/Application...

This feels very much like something I should be able to customize, but I unfortunately have no idea where to look for the option. Does anyone know how I can add additional file types to this menu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux Mint - add file type to "new file" context menu category](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/469981/linux-mint-add-file-type-to-new-file-context-menu-category)

Comment: @MarcusMüller That's interesting and unexpected, but it doesn't seem to have an effect yet. I'm going to be logging out and back in in a few hours after a job is done, I'll report back on whether it worked with a desktop restart then.

Comment: Thank you! That would be great, Michael.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Apologies for the delay, I was very busy yesterday and it slipped my mind. A restart did not change the behavior of KDE Plasma; it likely uses a different system from Cinnamon. I'm going to continue to investigate, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if there might be some trick with KMenuEdit that lets me alter the contextual menus too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's apparently necessary to add a `.desktop` file to `/usr/share/templates` or `~/.kde4/share/templates`. In the latter case, the `templates` folder should be created if necessary. See [Adding an entry to the Create New menu](https://userbase.kde.org/Adding_an_entry_to_the_Create_New_menu) in the KDE UserBase Wiki for more info.

Comment: For KDE5, it seems it needs to be /usr/share/templates (there's probably another single-user directory, but it isn't .kde and I may need to do some digging). Thank you!